# What is a best practice for ehcache clearStatistics() method replacement?

Tags: ehcache

I am trying to find the new best practice for clearing statistics on an ehcache Cache.  Previously, you would be able to call clearStatistics() and then you coul in real-time reset your stats on hit/miss operations.

Somewhere between ehcache 2.6 and 2.10, this went away.  However instead of seeing a release where it was deprecated and hints as to the new philosophy or suggested implementation strategy, I simply see the method gone from the API documentation: It is not shown in http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.10/deprecated-list.html#method nor http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/deprecated-list.html#method, and any previous versions are lost to refactoring on the site.

Answer (score 3):

`Cache.clearStatistics` has been removed in Ehcache 2.7.0. This release included a large rework of the Ehcache statistics to make them low overhead and ensure you paid the price only for statistics you queried and only for a limited period of time.

You can't clear statistics anymore inside Ehcache. If you need that feature, you have to use an external object that can handle the baselining for your application.

You can find the API documentation for each `<major>.<minor>` on http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/. And for the most recent versions, you can navigate to different fix versions even though there is no explicit link.
For example, see http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9.1/index.html

Disclaimer: I am working on Ehcache

Comment: But what this external object has to do to clear the statistics?

Comment: Instead of clearing stats, which is no longer a feature, you record their value at the time of _clear_ and then compute a difference between the new value and the recorded value. That baseline effectively gives the impression of a _clear_ to consumers.